# open-uri fails with Zlib::DataError: incorrect data check

Tags: ruby, zlib

I have a list of image urls (> 1000) that I need to download inside my ruby app. I'm using `open-uri` for this. I know that it has flaws, but it's handy if you have to support http, https and ftp.

The call itself is as simple as this

```
file = open(url) # an https url
```

After that the file is processed by Paperclip.

The problem is, that the call fails from time to time with a `Zlib::DataError`, even when using the same URLs over and over again. Sometimes they can be downloaded, sometimes an image throws an error. This is the stacktrace:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:382 in inflate
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:382 in block in inflate_adapter
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:497 in call_block
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:488 in <<
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:163 in read
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:405 in read
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:293 in block in read_body_0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:264 in inflater
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:283 in read_body_0
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:204 in read_body
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:352 in block (2 levels) in open_http
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1518 in block in transport_request
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:165 in reading_body
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1517 in transport_request
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1479 in request
/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.6.0.349/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:36 in block in request_with_newrelic_trace
/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.6.0.349/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:501 in disable_all_tracing
/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.6.0.349/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:35 in request_with_newrelic_trace
/gems/elastic-apm-2.3.1/lib/elastic_apm/spies/net_http.rb:54 in block in request
/gems/elastic-apm-2.3.1/lib/elastic_apm.rb:276 in with_span
/gems/elastic-apm-2.3.1/lib/elastic_apm/spies/net_http.rb:51 in request
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:343 in block in open_http
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:920 in start
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:337 in open_http
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:756 in buffer_open
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:226 in block in open_loop
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:224 in catch
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:224 in open_loop
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:165 in open_uri
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:736 in open
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:35 in open
```

I also downloaded the images with `wget` to see if the server sends a broken image, but it's hard to debug: You can't be sure if everything is ok because the server didn't return an error in this run, or if just everything is ok with the server and there is no error with it.

So I'm not sure if the error is caused by the server, or by open-uri or by...?

> So, to better debug this issue, I want to understand why ruby http does this `inflate` stuff and if I can get around it, OR if anyone has experienced something similar before.

Comment: I guess that the `inflate` method is used to decompress the response from the server (as webservers compress data). As this error happens randomly, this can be an inconsistency in the server response.

Comment: but I don't set any headers like `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate` in the request. Or do you mean some kind of transport compression (and not content compression)? If so, can you elaborate?

Comment: I found that [response.rb#L382](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_0/lib/net/http/response.rb#L382) "This allows a large response body to be inflated without storing the entire body in memory.", and the error description is [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_0/ext/zlib/zlib.c#L4860) "Usually if a stream was prematurely freed". So it _seems_ that the error is indeed in the server, and in your code, I would catch this error and retry the request with a little timeout.